# PyCharm can't seem to be able to import modules (random, webdriver)

Tags: selenium, import, pycharm

I recently installed MacOS BigSur, and updated to the latest version of PyCharm, but I think it totally broke it.
Indeed, I mostly use Selenium, and I had trouble installing the package, but I managed to do it via the mac terminal, using this command:

`/Users/inakivignal/PycharmProjects/NikeFP/venv/bin/python -m pip install selenium`

After that, it shows me errors from importing webdriver and even importing random. I don't know what else to do, because before it imported them directly from packages. I verified and selenium is indeed installed as an interpreter in this project.
I'll attach what it shows me when i put this code:

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrDoU.png)

I really don't know what is wrong with my PyCharm, if any of you could help me I would really appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that it is installed, you could right click on the error, then take the option "install package Selenium" looking like this: https://gyazo.com/2f7ed596192c772d164652e2a5fdbc0b
not sure if this helps but worth a try, also had problems with this

Comment: thanks, but it's not directly selenium the problem, it's that PyCharm can't seem to export things from it.

Comment: Thats why i would do it this way, i had a similar problem and this worked, or do you only get an error when running it?

Comment: nope, i get a problem while writing, all of the lines that refer to webdriver or driver or random get me an error, eventhough I just copy/paste a program that i had already wrote and that I know works for sure.

Comment: can you send a picture of the error and how it looks?